# Accessing files from Rails initialization code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the [gtfs library](http://rubygems.org/gems/gtfs). There's some long-running code that needs to be run on initialization (it needs to unzip a 118MB zip file):

```
source = GTFS::Source.build(<URI or Path to GTFS zip file>)
```

I tried to put the zip file in `/public` and then access it from `appplication.rb`:

```
config.after_initialize do
    puts "building GTFS"
    source = GTFS::Source.build("http://localhost:3000/gtfs-2014-02-14.zip")
    puts "built GTFS"
    source.each_agency {|agency| puts agency}
end
```

However, I got this error:

> /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/gtfs-0.2.2/lib/gtfs/url_source.rb:18:in `rescue in load_archive': Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000 (GTFS::InvalidSourceException)

Am I right in putting this initialization in `application.rb`? And how can I access files from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application won't be accepting requests while initializing. Does this work?

```
source = GTFS::Source.build("#{Rails.root}/public/gtfs-2014-02-14.zip")
```

Comment: It does, you saved my day! Another option which works locally but will cause more problems while deploying to a new server is: `source = GTFS::Source.build('/mywebsite/public/gtfs-2014-02-14.zip')`